# Should I ask one of my university lectures to be my mentor?

Tags: computer-science, mentoring

'm a computer science student in the UK and I've just finished my first year. I know next year I will be doing a lot more programming but there is very little C in the curriculum. I know some of my lecturers are avid C programmers would it be inappropriate to ask one of them to mentor me as I really want to be a competent C programmer or has anyone ever heard of less experienced students assisting with university research with their volunteered time?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like what you are looking for is less of a mentor and more of a tutor, who can work with you on basic skills and basic questions.  A mentor is more a person who you talk with infrequently to get advice.

As such, asking one of your lecturers to volunteer is likely to be inappropriate.  You might instead look to see if one of the upper level students might be interested---but if you need extensive tutoring, you will likely need to make it worth their while, whether that is in pay or in trade of same sort.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that your lecturer will be interested in one-on-one tutoring, but they may be willing to provide more general advice for where and how to learn the skill you are seeking to develop.  It is perfectly fine for you to approach your lecturer to ask their advice on learning programming, but just don't expect them to tutor you in it.  Perhaps you could seek some general guidance on finding appropriate learning resources, or getting tips for how to learn effectively.

As to seeking a more general mentoring role, that is probably quite premature at this stage in your degree.  This is something that usually happens when a lecturer works in a supervisory capacity for a student doing some kind of research topic.  This can occur in certain honours projects in undergraduate work or in a postgraduate research degree.  Since you are in first-year, it is likely that you have a lot of basics to learn before a mentoring role with a professional academic will be useful.  Nevertheless, you could flag your interest in this field with one of your lecturers and consider them as a possible future supervisor (e.g., for an honours project).